# Responsive link source for Picturefill

Tags: javascript, php, css, responsive-design, picturefill

I'm using Picturefill v2.3.1 and was wondering if someone knows a way to wrap the picture tag with a link which also reacts to the viewport width? My code is currently this:

```
<a href="" class="screenshot-lightbox">
    <picture>
        <source
            srcset="<?php echo $content->images()->find('medium_2x_'.$curlang.'.jpg')->url() ?> 2x"
            media="(min-width: 768px)">
        <source
            srcset="<?php echo $content->images()->find('medium_'.$curlang.'.jpg')->url() ?>"
            media="(min-width: 768px)">
        <source
            srcset="<?php echo $content->images()->find('small_2x_'.$curlang.'.jpg')->url() ?> 2x"
            media="(max-width: 767px)">
        <source
            srcset="<?php echo $content->images()->find('small_'.$curlang.'.jpg')->url() ?>"
            media="(max-width: 767px)">
        <img
            srcset="<?php echo $content->images()->find('small_'.$curlang.'.jpg')->url() ?>"
            media="(max-width: 767px)">
    </picture>
</a>
```

So for example I would like have an url in the "a href" for the first two sizes (medium) and then no url at all for the small sizes (last two).

Anyone know if this is possible somehow?

Comment: Note that your 1x sources will never be selected. You should actually just have one `source` element, something like:

Comment: <picture>
      <source
       srcset="medium_foo.jpg, medium_2x_foo.jpg 2x"
       media="(min-width: 768px)">
      <img
       srcset="small.jpg, small_2x.jpg 2x">
     </picture>

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you want this, or what it is you actually want. I suppose you have the link repeated as text, but don't want the image to be a link on small devices? Is it to reduce accidental touches? Is it OK to be able to tab to the link with the keyboard in that layout?

One way to disable clicks on the link (without affecting keyboard) is by using `pointer-events`:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .screenshot-lightbox { pointer-events: none; }
}
```

See http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: One example is that for retina screen user the a href should be an url to retina image and for non-retina screen user it should be non-retina image. The other case that you're referring to is that on mobile it hardly makes senses to open an image to a lightbox since it's already in full width on the page.

Comment: OK. Then just use JS. `<img onload="if (this.currentSrc.indexOf('medium') != -1) this.parentNode.parentNode.href = this.currentSrc;">`